# Actualizar base de datos con Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, webapi

Bien estoy usando Visual Studio 2017, tengo un proyecto en C# el cual tiene instalado Entity Framework en su versión 6.2.0 además de usar SQL Server 2008. (No estoy usando MVC sino Web API)

Lo que necesito es poder mapear mi modelo de base de datos en el proyecto de Visual Studio a mi base de datos en SQL Server, si bien entity framework me permite mapearlo con la opción en el visualizador de entidades llamada "Generar base de datos desde modelo..." este elimina todo registro de la base de datos en SQL Server a lo cual yo necesito que los datos ya registrados no se borren.

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto? Lo he intentado con "Code First Migrations" pero al hacer el Enable-Migrations me marca este error:

> Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created
>   using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be
>   obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing
>   DbCompiledModel.

mas sin embargo si me crea la carpeta Migrations y al ejecutar el comando

> add-migration InitialCreate

me marca el error anterior "Creating a DbModelBuilder..."

y ya no se genera alguna clase con los cambios que se hayan hecho en el modelo.

Cabe señalar que las entidades que genera Entity Framework de la Base de datos las tengo en un proyecto aparte llamado Entidades.

Comment: Hola, te creó el DBcontext??

Comment: Sí, eso lo genera Entity Framework.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que usar model-first está pensado para el caso de uso de un modelo que no evolucionará en el tiempo. Hay muy poca documentación para model-first, que al comienzo parecer ser ideal para un arquitecto de software. Al poco andar te das cuenta que ciertos casos de uso no son soportados (las migraciones).

Te sugiero generar otro modelo a partir de la base de datos (database-first). Si mapeaste correctamente los foreign keys, te vas a dar cuenta de que queda casi igual a tu modelo creado con model-first.

Code-first es para cuando creas clases que representan las tablas y sus relaciones. Si no partiste el proyecto con code first, te sugiero que uses database-first para no romper tu base de datos actual.